# Programmatically validate a user

Tags: 8, users

I have created a webform which when submitted will create a new user for my Drupal 8 site.

The user must enter his username, email, and some additional data.

I am using below code to create & validate a user:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
// use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\webformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission;

/**
 * Create New User Account when a webform submission is submitted.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "Create New User Account",
 *   label = @Translation("Create New User Account"),
 *   category = @Translation("Entity Create"),
 *   description = @Translation("Create New User Account when a webform submission is submitted."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class CreateNewAccountHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

// Function to be fired while submitting the Webform.
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

// Build Drupal DateTime & set correct format for your query.
  $current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();

// Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

    // Get 'Username' Value.
    $username = $values['username'];

    // Get 'Password' Value.
    $password = $values['password'];    

    // Get 'Full Name' Value.
    $FullName = $values['full_name']; 

    // Get 'Phone Number' Value.
    $PhoneNumber = $values['phone_number']; 

    // Get 'Email' Value.
    $email = $values['email'];

// Create user object.
    $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
    $new_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();

    //Mandatory fields.
    $new_user->setPassword($password);
    $new_user->setEmail($email);
    $new_user->setUsername($username);    // Alphanumeric (abc, 123), space ( ), period (.), hyphen (-), apostrophe ('), underscore ( _ ), and the @ sign are only allowed.
    $new_user->set("langcode", $language);
    $new_user->set("preferred_langcode", $language);
    $new_user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $language);
    $new_user->enforceIsNew();  // Set this to FALSE if you want to edit (resave) an existing user object.

    //Optional Fields
    $new_user->set("init", 'email');

    // Custom Fields
    $new_user->set("field_full_name", $FullName);
    $new_user->set("field_ph_nbr", $PhoneNumber);

    // Validate the user for possible errors.
    $violations = $new_user->validate();
    if (count($violations) > 0) {
      $property = $violations[0]->getPropertyPath();
      $msg      = $violations[0]->getMessage();

    // Show a custom message to user.
        \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t("$msg"));

      return FALSE;
    }

    // Activate the user Object (Status = Active).
    $new_user->activate();

    //Save user
    $new_user->save();

    // Get the new user ID.
    $new_user_id = $new_user->id();

    // Log in the user.
    user_login_finalize($new_user);
```

However, every time I try to create a new user using the webform, I got the below error:

```
This value is not a valid email address.
```

I have tried with:

- someone@hotmail.com
- someone@outlook.com
- someone@gmail.com

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: We'll need to see the code where you create the user, Ex: `$new_user = User::create([
      'name' => $user_name,
      'mail' => $user_mail,
    ]);` part.

Comment: @NoSssweat I have updated my question with full details

Comment: @kiamlaluno Please re-open my question as I updated it with full details.

Comment: I believe the problem is coming from `$new_user->set("init", 'email');`

Comment: yes, you don't need that code as you have already set the email with `setEmail`

Comment: So it is safe to delete this `$new_user->set("init", 'email');` ? if yes, please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Yes, it is safe to delete it. Can't add it as answer since this is closed, but don't worry about it.

Comment: Setting the *init* value for a User entity with a correct email address doesn't cause any issue, nor does it cause that error message. Differently from Drupal 7, *init* must be a valid email address, so *email* isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't specify which field caused the validation error. In this case, the error is caused by setting the *init* field with a value that isn't a valid email address.

Differently from Drupal 7, in Drupal 8 the *init* field for the User entity is created using the email datatype. (See [`User::baseFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/8.9.x).)

```
$fields['init'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('email')
  ->setLabel(t('Initial email'))
  ->setDescription(t('The email address used for initial account creation.'))
  ->setDefaultValue('');
```

Differently from the *mail* field, it doesn't get further constrains. (Compare the code used to create the *init* field with the following code.)

```
$fields['mail'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('email')
  ->setLabel(t('Email'))
  ->setDescription(t('The email of this user.'))
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->addConstraint('UserMailUnique')
  ->addConstraint('UserMailRequired')
  ->addConstraint('ProtectedUserField');
```

Still, as any entity field whose datatype is *email*, it has a constrain defined in the annotation of that datatype.

```
@DataType(
   id = "email",
   label = @Translation("Email"),
   constraints = {"Email" = {}}
)
```

(The classes defining that constraint are [`EmailConstraint`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Validation%21Plugin%21Validation%21Constraint%21EmailConstraint.php/class/EmailConstraint/8.9.x) and [`EmailValidator`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21validator%21Constraints%21EmailValidator.php/class/EmailValidator/8.9.x).)

Setting the *init* field for the User entity is optional, but it's generally used from administrators of a site when users claim they created an account for which they cannot retrieve the password they lost.
Depending on the purpose of the code you are using, you can either set the *init* field, or not. If you set it, it must set to a valid email value.

Comment: I understand that `init` field is optional and I would like to use it as it is important for later use; However, as mentioned in my question, using valid email address like: someone@hotmail.com, someone@outlook.com, someone@gmail.com (where "someone" is replaced by my name) does not succeeded and generated the mentioned error: `This value is not a valid email address.` when adding this `$new_user->set("init", 'email');` to my above code.

Comment: `$new_user->set("init", 'email')` doesn't set *init* to *someone@gmail.com* but to *email*, which indeed isn't a valid email address.

Comment: OMG ! I can't believe I missed out such mis-typing error, it is `$email` instead of `'email'`, thank you for pointing out to it